# Multivariate regression with a mix of ordinal and continuous dependent variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, markov-chain-montecarlo, multivariate-regression, dependent-variable

I would like to run a multivariate mixed regression MCMC model with two response (independent) variables, namely x and y. x is continuous while y is ordinal. There is one predictor variable that is continuous and one random effect. I would much appreciate if someone lets me know how to do this, and which package to use, preferably in R. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Check out `brms`, a package that is a very nice front end for `rstan`, which runs Bayesian models using `lme4` style syntax. It has a nice vignette on multivariate models. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_multivariate.html and then here is an example where the response variables are of different types https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/brms-multivariate-response-different-distributions/4939